# Resolving Russell's Paradox in NBG

Tags: logic, set-theory

> Looking back at the form of the paradox we see that we now have a way out. In order to derive $ R \in R$ we would need the extra assumption that $R$ is a set... contin
>
> Topoi, a categorical analysis of logic

To be clear, is the element relation undefined for proper classes?

Comment: You can think of Russell's Paradox as a "bug" (inconsistency) discovered in an early attempt to axiomatize set theory by G. Frege in the early 1900's. This bug was quickly eliminated in subsequent axiom systems introduced by Russell, Zermelo, Fraenkel and others, with ZFC being the dominant alternative for a century now. The notion of a class as distinct from a set was not needed to resolve this issue. There are no known inconsistencies in ZFC or in the other popular alternatives, e.g. NBG.

Comment: @MathGeek Not true. "The first incompleteness theorem states that no consistent system of axioms whose theorems can be listed by an effective procedure (i.e., an algorithm) is capable of proving all truths about the arithmetic of natural numbers. For any such consistent formal system, there will always be statements about natural numbers that are true, but that are unprovable within the system. The second incompleteness theorem, an extension of the first, shows that the system cannot demonstrate its own consistency." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems

Comment: @DanChristensen My mistake. Thanks to you I have learned something new.

Comment: The answer(which is accepted) is not quite correct, the element relation *does* make sense for classes(proper or not) in **NBG** set theory. The thing is that one usually has the axiom in **NBG** which states: "For all classes $X,Y$: if $X\in Y$ then $X$ is a set" this immediately implies that $A\in B$ is *false* if $A$ and $B$ are proper classes.

Comment: Could you write the correct answer/ @VioletFlame

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re looking for. As far as I can see my above comment answers your question.

Comment: No I mean convert your comment to answer @VioletFlame

Answer (score 1):

The way the proper class/set divide works is that sets can be elements of classes, but proper classes can't. A comprehension term $\{x: \varphi(x)\}$ denotes the class of all *sets* that satisfy $\varphi(x).$

Russel's paradox tells us that $R:=\{x: x\notin x\},$ the class of all sets that do not have themselves as members, cannot be a set. But there's no contradiction there since NBG does not promise us every comprehension term denotes a set. It just means $R$ must be a proper class, and that's fine.

(In ZFC the situation is a bit more nuanced, since we *are* promised every comprehension term denotes a set, but on the other hand, we are only allowed bounded comprehensions of the form $\{x\in y: \varphi(x)\}$... so what Russel's argument tells us is that there is no set $y$ containing all sets $x$ such that $x\notin x.$ Again, fine.)

As for whether the membership relation is defined when the LHS is a proper class, that's an implementation detail. One can formulate NBG in a two-sorted way, where classes and sets are different kinds of object (and saying a given class is proper just means there is no set with the same elements as it). In this case it is most natural to say $A\in B$ is syntactically illegal when $A$ is a class, so it is undefined in that sense. Or one can formulate it in a single-sorted way where all objects are classes and a set is a special type of class, in which case $A\in B$ is a well-defined, but false statement whenever $A$ is a proper class. Moreover, one can define what a set is this way: if a class is an member of some class, it is a set, otherwise it is a proper class.

Comment: The multisorted approach is more complicated, but then there will be two memebership relations one between two sets and one between a set and a class. So you can not call it "the" element relation.

Comment: @VioletFlame Yep, that’s true. Omitted that detail.